# Calculating the quadratic form of a vector and Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate the quadratic form $A = BQB^T$ where $Q = R \otimes S$. $R$ and $S$ are $[r,r]$ and $[s,s]$ square matrices, and $B$ is a $r \times s$ vector.

Can I express $A$ in terms of $B, R, S$ without actually having to compute $Q = R \otimes S$?

Comment: Break your B into two pieces?